# dlltool creating assembly file and empty library file

Tags: mingw

I have a def file that i am using to create a library file.  However when i try to do this with dlltool (from MinGW) all it does is create an assembly file and an empty library file.

The assembly file has a different name each time but the same contents.  Below are the contents of the assembly file.

```
# IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR
.section    .idata$2
.global _head_libnidaq_a
_head_libnidaq_a:
.rva    hname   #Ptr to image import by name list
#this should be the timestamp, but NT sometimes
#doesn't load DLLs when this is set.
.long   0   # loaded time
.long   0   # Forwarder chain
.rva    __libnidaq_a_iname  # imported dll's name
.rva    fthunk  # pointer to firstthunk
#Stuff for compatibility
.section    .idata$5
fthunk:
.section    .idata$4
hname:
```

Doees anybody have any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Can you show the command you're using to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25343929/mingw-dlltool-creates-empty-file) two years after this question was asked, this problem occurs if the directory containing as.exe (typically [installation location]/mingw32/bin) is not on the system path. Unfortunately dlltool only warns about this (by echoing the "no such file or directory" error generated when trying to run as.exe) if run with the verbose flag (-v).

Running the command `set PATH=%PATH%;[installation location]/mingw32/bin` in the Windows command prompt and then running dlltool resolves this issue.