# MinGW dlltool creates empty file

Tags: c, mingw, dlltool

I'm trying to build static library using MinGW dlltool in order too link it in GCC. What I have is only a DLL file. I created a *.def file and now I'm trying to make *.a file. However I can't force MinGW dlltool to create antyhing, it only makes an empty file. Here's the console output:

```
C:\MinGW\bin>dlltool -v -d nlib32.def -l nlib32.a
dlltool: Processing def file: nlib32.def
dlltool: LIBRARY: NCAPI32.dll base: ffffffff
dlltool: Processed def file
dlltool: Processing definitions
dlltool: Processed definitions
dlltool: Creating library file: nlib32.a
dlltool: run: as   -o dozwch.o dozwch.s
dlltool: No such file or directory
dlltool: CreateProcess
```

What's the problem? How can I create the static library file?

Comment: You appear to be missing the `as` command. Check your installation.

Comment: @RossRidge There is an executable "as.exe" in my C:\MinGW\bin folder. I've already tried reinstalling MinGW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. Adding C:\MinGW\bin (or wherever your as.exe is located) to system PATH solved it for me.

Comment: I also had the same trouble for windeployqt.exe tool from Qt suite. It seems to be a common trouble for all GNU tool ports for windows.

Comment: had the same problem and found out that you need the path has to be without any spaces, i.e. `c:\program files\mingw\bin` won't work.

Comment: clearing PATH altogether  works too (set PATH=)